# HTML formatted content in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, webbrowser-control, powerpoint

I am creating PowerPoint slides programatically. I'm populating them with content from Team Foundation Server. This content might include HTML tags for formatting (pretty simple stuff like type face (bold, italic, etc.) or lists). Including this content as normal PowerPoint paragraphs ends up with these HTML tags shown as literal text. Instead, I want this text to show up as it was formatted in TFS.

My approach was to insert a WebBrowser component into my slide. I had to modify some registry keys to loosen some security restrictions in PowerPoint 2016 and set the web engine to be used from inside the WebBrowser component, found here and here.

The presentation then has to be a macro-enabled one. The content might be set by a VBA event method during presentation. I've seen this working with the event method calling WebBrowser.Navigate to call an existing URL, like this:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "www.google.com"
End Sub
```

But what I need is to set the Document content. So my code looks rather like this:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    Dim sHTML As String
    sHTML = "<P>This is some text.</P>"

    WebBrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML = sHTML  
End Sub
```

(taken from MSDN.)

Unfortunately, trying to access WebBrowser.Document returns Nothing in VBA.

Do you have any idea how to access the Document property (some more security settings?). Or maybe you have got some completely different but even more effective idea?

Comment: It might be worth parsing the HTML to locate and remove the bold/ital/etc tags but record the character positions where each of them occurs, then once the "de-tagged" text is pasted into PPT, use those positions to construct ranges to which you apply bold/italic/etc.  That way you end up with plain PPT text and no need for macro-enabled presentations and no requirement for each recipient of the presentation to make registry settings to enable the web browser control.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve. Sounds reasonable. But it leads into "parsing-hell" in a way. What to parse? Where to stop? What about lists, tables, etc. etc.

Comment: True, parsing will cost you more or less hair depending on how far from "simple" your HTML strays. And how much of it you need to fit onto a slide, considering that PPT won't scroll the content, where HTML in a web browser control will.